# jQuery Mobile Duplicate Triggers Explained

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-on

I understand that when you create a listener in jQuery Mobile like:

`$('.this-class').on('swipe',tapHandler);`

tapHandler will run twice. In order to eliminate this problem I have seen multiple solutions, such as:

`$('.page-card').off('swipe').on('swipe',tapHandler);`

or

wrapping it in side of `pageinit` in order to eliminate chaching issues if you are creating dynamic content within `pagebeforeshow` as seen [here](http://richardsweeney.com/jquery-mobile-events-firing-multiple-times-and-what-to-do-about-it/).

I also understand that even bubbling comes in to play here.

However, I was hoping that someone could explain why this **known** exists, and why the contributes to jQuery decided to take this route, knowing the drawbacks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't bind it twice? AFAIR, I never had this problem with the swipe event.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I'm not binding twice. The first code example is only found once. The only thing in the `tapHandler()` function is `console.log('trigger');` Every time I swipe I get the "trigger" message twice.

Answer (score 2):

First lets discuss how **`jQuery Mobile`** works. Unlike normal web pages where **`jQuery`** is used **`jQuery Mobile`** uses ajax to load pages into the **`DOM`**, one or more pages can be loaded. Because of this, classic document ready is useless so **`jQM`** developers created page events.

Page events are major for this story. While document ready will trigger only one per page most of page events will trigger multiple times, depending on how much time page is re/visited.

Lets get back to **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function (and all other similar functions like **[bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**, [**delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), deprecated **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**). Again when working on normal pages you will NEVER come to situation because same page will never stay in a **`DOM`**.

Here comes **`jQuery Mobile`**. If you are using a binding method inside a pageshow (or similar page event) that event will bind over and over. Basically **`on`** method was never intended to be used  like this.

If you want to find out more about methods of prevention take a look at my other **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**, look for topic: **Prevent multiple event binding/triggering**

Comment: Ok. My problem is that when running `$('.this-class').on('swipe',tapHandler);`, tapHandler is initiated twice on a single swipe, even if I haven't moved to a different view. What makes this happen?

Comment: Can't tell you without seeing your code. Can you mail me your project or at least create a smaller skeleton version so I can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 var isDown = false;
 $('.page-card').off().on('swipe',tapHandler);
 $('body').off('vmousedown').on('vmousedown',down);
 $('body').off('vmouseup').on('vmouseup',isUp);
 $('body').off('vmousemove').on('vmousemove',recorder);
 function tapHandler(event) {
  console.log(event);
 }
 function down(event) {
  isDown = true;
  console.log('down');
 }
 function isUp(event) {
  isDown = false;
  console.log('up');
 }
 function recorder(event) {
  if(isDown) {
   console.log('moving');
   return event.pageX;
  }
 }
});`

The entire file. Just testing some things for now.